# html hyperlink - adds automatic break

Tags: html, hyperlink

My button "TEST" is not in the same linke as my text. So the hyperlink does not come directly after the word "hyperlink" in my text but it adds a automatic break. And I dont understand why.

```html
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
    <h3>TITLE!</h4>
    <p class="mb-3">
    Just some text
    <br>
    Some more text
    </p>
    <br>
    <h3>Second Title</h4>
    <p class="mb-3">
    Some text that will contain a hyperlink
    <br>
    HYPERLINK 
    <a href="https://google.com" target="_top">Test</a>
    some more following text
    </p>
    <br>**strong text**
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no break between the word "HYPERLINK" and the "Test" link in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should contain much more information (i.e. relevant code), but basically the `a` tag which contains the "TEST" tag needs to be an inline element to allow subsquent text to be on the same line (which it isn't, judging from the behaviour you describe).

Apply a class or ID to it and create a CSS rule for that class or ID wich contains `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Thank you for you help first of all. You are right, I should of posted the css as well. 

That was also the problem. display: inline-block helped. 

Thank you!